# U-substitute $\int_0^\pi \sin(t-nwt)dt $

Tags: calculus

I have an integral which I decided to solve by u-substitution. But I get stuck after differentiating u, how should I solve it further?

$$\int_0^\pi \sin(t-nwt)dt = \begin{Bmatrix} u = t-nwt\\ du = 1-nw dt\\ du-1=-nwdt\\ \frac{du-1}{-nw}=dt\end{Bmatrix} = \int_0^\pi \sin(u)\frac{du-1}{-nw}= ??$$ Am I thinking in the right way here? Because now, du is in the middle of the integral and I think that I would want it at the end...

Comment: Very complicate for such an easy thing... moreover, what you did is wrong, with your notation, if $u=t-nwt$, then $$\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}t-nw\mathrm{d}t=(1-nw)\mathrm{d}t\implies \mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-nw}.$$

Comment: That solved everything! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An easier way:**

$$\int_0^\pi \sin(t-nwt)dt=\int_0^\pi\sin\big((1-nw)t\big)dt=\left[-\frac{1}{1-nw}\cos\big((1-nw)t\big)\right]_0^\pi=...$$

Comment: I am confused, where did the *du* dissapear?

Comment: what do you mean ? for the substitution, I answered in a comment under your question.

Comment: I see, the comment solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Let $(1-nw)t=u$ so we have $dt=\frac{1}{1-nw}du$ and so $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(t-nwt)\, dt=\int_{0}^{\pi} \, \frac{\sin u}{1-nw}du=\frac{1}{1-nw}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin u\,du$$ therefore we see that  $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(t-nwt)\, dt=\left[\frac{-1}{1-nw}\cos u \right]_{0}^{\pi}=\left[\frac{-1}{1-nw}\cos (1-nw)t \right]_{0}^{\pi}$$